how to replace place holders in an typescript object using another object
I need to replace some place holders in an object using values from another object. My object with place holders looks like below
const programmer  = {
  firstname: "Phil {ReplaceMeWithValue1}",
  age: 21,
  backendDeveloper: true,
  skillLevels: { "JavaScript": "basic {ReplaceMeWithValue1}", "Java": "Intermediate {ReplaceMeWithValue1}"},
  currentProjectName: "The Amazing App {ReplaceMeWithValue2}"
};

And the object that contains values looks like
 const dataToReplace = { "ReplaceMeWithValue1": "ReplacingValue1", "ReplaceMeWithValue2": "ReplacingValue2" };

I'm trying something like below but not able to figure that out
ngOnInit(): void {
const programmer  = {
  firstname: "Phil {ReplaceMeWithValue1}",
  age: 21,
  backendDeveloper: true,
  skillLevels: { "JavaScript": "basic {ReplaceMeWithValue1}", "Java": "Intermediate {ReplaceMeWithValue1}"},
  currentProjectName: "The Amazing App {ReplaceMeWithValue2}"
};

const dataToReplace = { "ReplaceMeWithValue1": "ReplacingValue1", "ReplaceMeWithValue2": "ReplacingValue2" };

Object.keys(programmer).forEach(key => {
  this.replacePlaceHolders(programmer[key as keyof typeof programmer], dataToReplace);
});
 }

replacePlaceHolders(value: string | number | boolean | { JavaScript: string; Java: string; }, dataToReplace: { ReplaceMeWithValue1: string; ReplaceMeWithValue2: string; }) {
 Object.keys(dataToReplace).forEach(key => {
 value = value?.replace(`{${key}}`, dataToReplace[key as keyof typeof dataToReplace]) || value;  
  });
 }

}
The converted object should look like below
const programmer  = {
  firstname: "Phil ReplacingValue1",
  age: 21,
  backendDeveloper: true,
  skillLevels: { "JavaScript": "basic ReplacingValue1", "Java": "Intermediate ReplacingValue1"},
  currentProjectName: "The Amazing App ReplacingValue2}"
};


I think current code parser is broken.
class YourComponentClass {
// start

public ngOnInit(): void {

    const programmer = {
        firstname: "Phil {ReplaceMeWithValue1}",
        age: 21,
        backendDeveloper: true,
        skillLevels: {
            "JavaScript": "basic {ReplaceMeWithValue1 }",
            "Java": "Intermediate {ReplaceMeWithValue1}"
        },
        currentProjectName: "The Amazing App {ReplaceMeWithValue }"
    };

    const dataToReplace = {
        "ReplaceMeWithValue1": "ReplacingValue1",
        "ReplaceMeWithValue2": "ReplacingValue2"
    };

    this._interpolateObjectValues(programmer, dataToReplace);
}

private _interpolateObjectValues<
    T extends object,
    U extends Record<PropertyKey, string>
>(obj: T, dataToReplace: U): void {
    for (const key in obj) {
        const value = obj[key];
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            Reflect.set(obj, key, this._interpolateValue(value, dataToReplace));
        } else if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
            this._interpolateObjectValues(value, dataToReplace);
        }
    }
}

private _interpolateValue<U extends Record<PropertyKey, string>>(value: string, dataToReplace: U): string {
    for (const key in dataToReplace) {
        value = value.replace(new RegExp(`\\{\\s*${key}\\s*\\}`, "g"), dataToReplace[key]);
    }
    return value;
}

// end

}
